# HTTP not supported when using GLib’s GIO APIs

Tags: python, pygobject, gio

I'm writing a GTK application that sometimes downloads files with HTTP. Since I don't want to block normal execution, I obviously can't use urllib or Requests, so I'm trying to use GIO instead. However, I'm getting a `GLib.Error: g-io-error-quark: Operation not supported (15)` when downloading a file over HTTP (`file://` works fine).

```
from gi.repository import Gio
print(Gio.File.new_for_uri("file:///etc/profile").load_contents(None))
print(Gio.File.new_for_uri("http://example.org").load_contents(None))
```

The first statement (the `file://`) works as expected, but the second one (`http://`) gives the aforementioned error (full output below). In my real program, I use the async version, but the sync version is shorter and gives the same error.

```
(True, contents=b'# /etc/profile\n\n [-snip-]')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/gio.py", line 3, in <module>
    print(Gio.File.new_for_uri("http://example.org").load_contents(None))
GLib.Error: g-io-error-quark: Operation not supported (15)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ensure you have the `http` backend for GVFS installed, and that your program has access to the D-Bus session bus which `gvfsd` is running on.

The GVFS backends are normally provided in a distribution package like [`gvfs-backends`](https://packages.debian.org/jessie/gnome/gvfs-backends).

GIO does not include support for loading URIs other than `file://` URIs by default. For all other URIs, it communicates with the GVFS daemon, which in turn does the actual I/O.

Comment: Seems it's `gvfs` on Arch.

Comment: The same error message can come from gtk.show_uri(), when trying to launch an application to show an https: or file: URI. For anyone else who finds their way here while chasing that problem, use commands like `gio mime x-scheme-handler/https firefox.desktop` or `gio mime inode/directory file-manager.desktop` to register an application as a handler for the mime type in question. (The corresponding .desktop file must exist in the appropriate place, of course.)